# How to save with .mp3 instead of .wav?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to make a voice recorder, in this portion of code the file is saved with the `.wav`format but i prefere the `.mp3` format, how to save the file with the .mp3 extension? I think that `SoundFile` can't use mp3 because `if i write .mp3 instead of .wav` the program gives me an error, thanks

```
with sf.SoundFile("output.wav", mode='w', samplerate=44100,channels=2) as file:
   #Create an input stream to record audio without a preset time
           with sd.InputStream(samplerate=44100, channels=2, callback=callback):
               while recording == True:
                   #Set the variable to True to allow playing the audio later
                   file_exists =True
                   #write into file
                   file.write(q.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Soundfile, or, more precisely, [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/#Features), does not support mp3. Consider using a different library (e.g. [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)). Here's an example where I am writing a sine wave to mp3:

```
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment

sample_rate = 48000
frequency = 440 # Hz
length = 3 # in seconds

t = np.linspace(0, length, sample_rate * length) 
y = np.sin(frequency * 2 * np.pi * t).astype("float32")  #  Has frequency of 440Hz

audio_segment = AudioSegment(
    y.astype("float32").tobytes(), 
    frame_rate=sample_rate,
    sample_width=y.dtype.itemsize, 
    channels=1
)

audio_segment.export("test.mp3", format="mp3", bitrate="128k")
```

Comment: Hi ok i understand thanks for the help, i would really really appreciate if you check my question i updated with the full code, could you implement pydub in my code for saving the file in .mp3? I think you should go in the record_audio() function and replace SoundFile with pydub, if you can do it i can event mark as correct answer and upovote i would really appreciate it

Comment: @Forty966699669 No, I can't, live recording is a different matter and a different question. I answered the original question, also provided the code. Live recording to mp3 requires a different solution.

Comment: Traceswki thanks i updated the question with the original code so your answers is more correct in respect of you, if you have pleasure to help me i made a new question about the live recording https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72636529/how-to-convert-wav-into-mp3

Comment: @Forty966699669 If I answered your question, consider accepting the answer. Please do the same for all other questions you raised. I will have a look at your new question then.